# Shrinking ESXi volume to reclaim unallocated space

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, lvm, fdisk, partition-table

We have a number of VMs (VMware ESXi) running Ubuntu. As a result of the installation time 'feature' which only allocates half the amount of the requested space, we have a lot of wasted/unallocated space. For example, a 100Gb volume as seen by the OS is taking 200Gb in ESXi.

There are lots of articles describing how to correct this by extending the OS volume to take the full 200Gb - but I'd like to do the opposite: keep the OS volume as 100Gb but shrink the space consumed in ESXi down to 100Gb too.

I'm confused regarding the LVMs, logical volumes, physical volumes, the use of parted, fdisk, editing the VMDK file etc. What are the steps to complete this safely?

Thanks,